# Partial dependence plot from an xgboost model in R

Tags: r, xgboost

Is there an already existing function to get a partial dependence plot from an xgboost model in R? I saw examples of using `mlr` package, but it seems to require an `mlr`-specific wrapper class. I am a little unclear if there is a way to convert an `xgboost` model into that class.

Comment: Would love an answer on this

Comment: It might be worthwhile to use the whole `mlr` pipeline for this process. It is nicely explained in the [tutorial on how to generate partial dependence plots with mlr](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/partial_dependence/index.html#generating-partial-dependences). You just have to replace "classif.ksvm" with "classif.xgboost" and generate a task from your data with `mlr::makeClassifTask()`.

Answer (score 6):

I have been working on an R package, `pdp`, for constructing partial dependence plots--https://github.com/bgreenwell/pdp. I was able to get it to work with XGBoost models, but it is still experimental. There is a  vignette/manuscript in progress in the manuscript folder that may help.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do the trick without converting to `mlr`: https://github.com/FeiYeYe/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/R/plot.xgb.Booster.R

Comment: I don't think this plots the partial dependence.  For each bin of the chosen predictor, it grabs the median of the predicted value among the observations that fall into this bin.  For partial dependence, every single observation should be used to calculate the average value for that bin.

Comment: I am not sure you’re right. See this: `indices_bucket <- which(data[, index] >= pred_var_x[i-1] & data[, index] < pred_var_x[i])`. That grabs the observations and makes predictions on every single one of them: `preds_bucket <- xgboost::predict(object, data[indices_bucket, , drop = FALSE], 
          missing = NA, ntreelimit = ntrees)`, then get the median of the predictions: `pred_var_y[i - 1] <- median(preds_bucket, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: `indices_bucket` tells us which rows where the predictor of interest (`data[, index]`) falls in the bucket.  This is not all rows.  Then when `predict` is called, it only applies to those rows, not all rows.

Comment: What are “all rows” then?

Comment: "All rows" would be a call to `predict` without any subset on `data`. For the predictor of interest (index), you actually have to pass in every possible value of that predictor for each row. That's when it gets computationally intensive for a large data set.

Comment: OK, so you do cross-join on all the variables you want to put into the partial dependence plot and then take medians for the results for each values of the predictor?